# Links worked before but after a recent update it fails?

Tags: html, css

I had the navigation before working, where when you hovered over the nav it would highlight red and be clickable (To take you to another URL). After I plugged in some other codes, it seems to not work anymore.. any suggestions?

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/header.png" />
    </div>
    <img src="images/navbar.png" />
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.voyage-us.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.voyage-us.com/xenforo/upload/index.php">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Streams</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mainbody">
        <img src="images/mainbody.png" /></div>

    <div class="news1">
        <img src="images/news1.png" /></div>

    <div class="teamspeak">  <!--Teamspeak IMG-->
        <img src="images/teamspeak.png" /></div>

    <div id="ts3viewer_1037062" /></div>  <!-- Teamspeak Widget -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tsviewer.com/short_expire/js/ts3viewer_loader.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var ts3v_url_1 = "http://www.tsviewer.com/ts3viewer.php?ID=1037062&text=000000&text_size=12&text_family=2&js=1&text_s_color=ffffff&text_s_weight=bold&text_s_style=normal&text_s_variant=normal&text_s_decoration=none&text_s_color_h=ffffff&text_s_weight_h=bold&text_s_style_h=normal&text_s_variant_h=normal&text_s_decoration_h=underline&text_i_color=ffffff&text_i_weight=normal&text_i_style=normal&text_i_variant=normal&text_i_decoration=none&text_i_color_h=ffffff&text_i_weight_h=normal&text_i_style_h=normal&text_i_variant_h=normal&text_i_decoration_h=underline&text_c_color=ffffff&text_c_weight=normal&text_c_style=normal&text_c_variant=normal&text_c_decoration=none&text_c_color_h=ffffff&text_c_weight_h=normal&text_c_style_h=normal&text_c_variant_h=normal&text_c_decoration_h=underline&text_u_color=ffffff&text_u_weight=bold&text_u_style=normal&text_u_variant=normal&text_u_decoration=none&text_u_color_h=ffffff&text_u_weight_h=bold&text_u_style_h=normal&text_u_variant_h=normal&text_u_decoration_h=none";
        ts3v_display.init(ts3v_url_1, 1037062, 100);
        -->
        </script>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy;2014 Rythmn Designs<p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: url("http://puu.sh/6RlKi.png")
}

.clear
{
clear:both;
}

#page-wrap
{
width: 1019px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

#nav
{
height: 0.1px;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 14px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin: -14px;
margin-top: -15px;
}

#nav li a
{
position:relative;
top: -12px;
display: block;
width: 100px;
float: left;
color: white;
font-size:  14.09px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:"BankGothic Md BT"
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active
{
color: red;
}

#mainbody
{
vertical-align:top;
position:relative
}

.news1
{
position: absolute;
top: 435px;
right: 815px
}

.teamspeak
{
position: absolute;
top: 435px;
right: 470px

}

#ts3viewer_1037062
{
position:absolute;
top: 465px;
right: 478px;
width: 290px;
height:190px;
overflow:auto;
}

#footer
{
background: #181818;
color: white;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-top: 15px solid #828080;
text-align: center;
font-family:"BankGothic Md BT";
font-size:  12px;
position: relative;
}
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE to toy with - http://jsfiddle.net/rdL2m/

Comment: Why is the code in the widget commented out?

Comment: No clue - Copied it from the TS website but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Apply these styles exactly as they appear to the #nav:

```
#nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 352px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Nothing else should be included. Only what you see above should be applied to the #nav.

Now, in your '#nav li a' styles, **remove** these completely:

```
{
  top: -12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Now to your li's, add:

```
#nav li { 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Your menu should be in great shape. No all you have to do is apply left/right padding to the li's or the anchor elements to achieve the desired spacing between links.

Comment: The closing div at the end is the one for the page-wrap. I tried putting a closing div after the footer and nothing changes.

Comment: I'd also get rid of that margin of -14px and margin-top of -15px on the nav. Once I removed those, the hover functionality worked fine.

Comment: The margins are the reason it's on top of the nav bar. If I take those out, it just goes underneath.

Comment: There's a height of 0.1px on the ul#nav. You can only have pixels in increments of 1.

Comment: Also, take out the top: -12px and float left off of the #nav li a elements. That's what's killing your hover effect. The way you're positioning your elements. If you want to throw up a jsfiddle with some placeholder images, it would make this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the menu items in header **div** and also make a separate **div** for the navigation bar. You also forgot to close **div** for footer.

Comment: That works, but now I'm going to have to re-position everything. Is that the only way?

Comment: This is a well-structured way. I personally recommend you to follow that way and keep things simple and clean